# Add processing indicator to shiny when check all in selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

I am using shiny to build web application. I have about 500+ variables, so whenever I tried to check all in selectInput, it takes about 30-60 sec. Is there any way to add a  processing indicator when selectInput is working(not when calculating)? Thanks!

Comment: Lots of examples exist for building progress indicators for Shiny. Here https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-incubator/blob/master/inst/examples/progress/server.R is one